# bundle.js:50930 Uncaught TypeError: require(...).createServer is not a function

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, browserify

I have integrated stripe api in my website. I have created bundle.js using stripe, express and http-browserify. and encountered this error:

> bundle.js:50930 Uncaught TypeError: require(...).createServer is not a
>   function
>        at Object.
>
> at Object.require.stripe.../package.json
>
> at s bundle.js:1:262
>        at /post.html:11:14(anonymous function)
>
> @ bundle.js:50930require.stripe.../package.json
>
> @ bundle.js:51112s
>
> @ bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ post.html:11

When I click on error it give error on :

```
Stripe.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = require('http').createServer().timeout;
```

Comment: You did not get where to read timeout value and You did that trick? (:

Answer (score 4):

You used the server-side [`stripe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe) package, of which [the documentation states](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#these-are-serverside-bindings-only):

> ## **These are serverside bindings only**
>
> If you're looking to install stripe.js, our clientside tokenization library - this is not it. These are serverside node.js bindings only.

You can't use these in a browser.

The client-side library, `stripe.js`, isn't available from NPM so you need to add it to your client-side code the old-fashioned way, by using:

```
<script src='https://js.stripe.com/v2/'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If You're using this code on clientside:

```
You cannot, at least You've to provide this `timeout` param from backend.
or just hardcode it and etc.
```

If You're using this code on serverside so... :

The problem is because of: `createServer()`

from [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener):

> http.createServer([requestListener])
>
> ## Added in: v0.1.13
>
> ```
> Returns: <http.Server>
> ```
>
> Returns a new instance of http.Server.
>
> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the
>   'request' event.

To get at least timeout value You've to pass an empty function to achieve successfully creation of http server.

So dirty fix:

```
Stripe.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = require('http').createServer(function(){}).timeout;
```